# PHP: Pass by reference

Tags: php, pass-by-reference

Passing by reference:

```
<?php
$str = "test    \n";
trim(&$str);
echo "-" . "$str" . "-";
?>
```

output is:

```
-test
-
```

but when I do

```
<?php
$str = "test    \n";
$str = trim($str);
echo "-" . "$str" . "-";
?>
```

the output is:

```
-test-
```

Why can't I pass this by reference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `trim()` does not expect a reference and thus does not modify the string that was passed to it. Passing a reference only makes sense if the function expects one - and then you do not have the choice of *not* passing a reference since what matters if the function *definition* contains a reference argument or not.

What you are trying to do, call-time pass-by-reference is [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) in PHP since a long time. Besides that, even if it wasn't deprecated it would only work for functions that actually modify the argument.

> Note: There is no reference sign on a function call - only on function definitions. Function definitions alone are enough to correctly pass the argument by reference. As of PHP 5.3.0, you will get a warning saying that "call-time pass-by-reference" is deprecated when you use `&` in `foo(&$a);`.

Comment: Why have they deprecated this in php?

Comment: Because it makes no sense at all. For CTPBR to be useful the caller needs to know details about the function's implementation. And depending on how the function is written, it could even have unexpected side-effects.

Answer (score 1):

Please see the reference:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

If you read the manual, you will understand that `trim()` isn't expecting a reference of string but the value of `string` itself.

Answer (score 1):

Lets check what [PHP Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) says about this:

> Note:  There is no reference sign on a function call - only on function definitions. Function definitions alone are enough to correctly pass the argument by reference. As of PHP 5.3.0, you will get a warning saying that "call-time pass-by-reference" is deprecated...

Look at the [`trim`](http://hu2.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) signature:

```
string trim ( string $str [, string $charlist ] )
```

There's nothing about `$str` would be passed by reference. So it won't. Function `trim` will only use your input to generate the the output, but won't modify it - it can't anyways, because `$str` is not passed by reference.